# Android manually select layout folder

Tags: android, android-layout

In Android is it possible to select layout directory programmatically (in my case select the `layout-land` layout when I request)?

The reason I am asking is that in my application I am having hard time adopting it do various screen proportions, and the default Android logic of picking the layout file from `layout-land` or from `layout` does not work for me. It would be much better if I could manually decide which proportion is considered landscape. And I do not want to fix the screen orientation.

Answer (score 0):

> In Android is it possible to select layout directory programmatically (in my case select the layout-land layout when I request)?

No, sorry.

> the default Android logic of picking the layout file from layout-land or from layout does not work for me

Then use other resource set qualifiers, such as `-wNNNdp` (use these layouts for devices whose current width is NNN `dp` or larger) or `-swNNNdp` (use these layouts for devices whose smallest width, in any orientation, is NNN `dp` or larger).

If none of those suffice, you will need to have distinct layout resources (e.g., `activity_main.xml` and `activity_main_other.xml`), and request those yourself based on your own criteria.

Comment: This will not work with resource qualifiers for me because I have to know the proportions of the screen (rather than size limits) to be able to decide which layout to render.

I tried your second suggestion, but I cannot get the (non-zero) size of the activity in `onCreate()`, so I cannot determine which layout resource to put into `setContentView()`.

Comment: @Vic: "I cannot get the (non-zero) size of the activity in onCreate()" -- `DisplayMetrics` should be working. Alternatively, try a `ViewTreeObserver` to find out when the `android.R.id.content` container is laid out, get the dimensions at that point, and make decisions from there. Or, redesign the UI to not be quite this sensitive to aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

You can force your activities to be always in a landscape mode [see here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

```
<activity
...
      android:screenOrientation="landscape"
...
/>
```

but note that

> If your application targets Android 3.2 (API level 13) or higher, then you should also declare the "screenSize" configuration, because it also changes when a device switches between portrait and landscape orientations.

And you can set the same data in your code as well.

```
myActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: Thank you, I know it would be the easiest solution, but I don't want to force the users just to one screen orientation.

Comment: You can force it when it's needed only, and then leave it for the sensor to decide